# Checking for legal sudoku boards

Tags: python, python-2.x, sudoku

My problem statement is:

> Write a function to indicate if a given Sudoku board is legal. This function takes a Sudoku board *(which you may assume is a N2xN2 2d list of integers, where N is an integer)*, and returns `True` if the board is legal, as described above.

And here's my solution:

```
import time, random

def solve_all(grids, name='', showif=0.0):
    """Attempt to solve a sequence of grids. Report results.
    When showif is a number of seconds, display puzzles that take longer.
    When showif is None, don't display any puzzles."""
    def time_solve(grid):
        start = time.clock()
        values = solve(grid)
        t = time.clock()-start
        ## Display puzzles that take long enough
        if showif is not None and t > showif:
            display(grid_values(grid))
            if values: display(values)
            print '(%.2f seconds)\n' % t
        return (t, solved(values))
    times, results = zip(*[time_solve(grid) for grid in grids])
    N = len(grids)
    if N > 1:
        print "Solved %d of %d %s puzzles (avg %.2f secs (%d Hz), max    %.2f secs)." % (
            sum(results), N, name, sum(times)/N, N/sum(times), max(times))

def solved(values):
    "A puzzle is solved if each unit is a permutation of the digits 1 to 9."
    def unitsolved(unit): return set(values[s] for s in unit) == set(digits)
    return values is not False and all(unitsolved(unit) for unit in unitlist)

def from_file(filename, sep='\n'):
    "Parse a file into a list of strings, separated by sep."
    return file(filename).read().strip().split(sep)

def random_puzzle(N=17):
    """Make a random puzzle with N or more assignments. Restart on contradictions.
    Note the resulting puzzle is not guaranteed to be solvable, but empirically
    about 99.8% of them are solvable. Some have multiple solutions."""
    values = dict((s, digits) for s in squares)
    for s in shuffled(squares):
        if not assign(values, s, random.choice(values[s])):
            break
        ds = [values[s] for s in squares if len(values[s]) == 1]
        if len(ds) >= N and len(set(ds)) >= 8:
            return ''.join(values[s] if len(values[s])==1 else '.' for s in squares)
    return random_puzzle(N) ## Give up and make a new puzzle

def shuffled(seq):
    "Return a randomly shuffled copy of the input sequence."
    seq = list(seq)
    random.shuffle(seq)
    return seq
```

Comment: Your code does not work as is, you seem to be using undeclared global variables everywhere, `digits`, `squares`, `unitlist`... Plus, none of the functions you have posted seem to do what your question says!

Comment: Purists might also look for requirement for symmetry to be validated/enforced ?  
N^2 x N^2 ?
 If N > 3 then "digit" set will be larger than {1..9} ?

Answer (score 3):

#### Coding style

Please follow [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the style guide for Python code.
As you read through it, you should recognize several coding style violations in your posted code. 
There is also a command line tool called `pep8`, which can check your entire project and report the violations. You can install it with:

```
pip install pep8
```

#### Strange condition

This looks very strange:

> ```
> return values is not False and all(unitsolved(unit) for unit in unitlist)
> ```

From the posted code it's not clear what is the type of `values`.
The plural name implies some kind of collection,
but then it can never be `False`.
As such, this condition doesn't make sense.